# Why does `my_list` and `my_list[:]` return different outputs for a simple recursive algorithm?

Tags: python

I wrote the following algorithm:

```py
def get_permutations(nums):
    combos = []
    n = len(nums)

    def add_permutations(nums, combo=[]):
        # when the combos hit the target length, it's complete
        if len(combo) == n:
            combos.append(combo[:])
        # otherwise, you just keep adding to the combo with the remaining nums
        for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
            # add to combo and get remaining nums
            combo.append(num)
            remaining_nums = nums[:idx] + nums[idx + 1:]
            # call again at new call depth
            add_permutations(remaining_nums, combo)
            # remove last addition so base combo remains same for all calls at this level
            combo.pop()

    add_permutations(nums)
    return combos

nums = [1,2,3]
print(get_permutations(nums))
```

This returns

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

But if I make a tiny modification of `combo[:]` ==> `combo`, it returns empty lists.

```py
def get_permutations(nums):
    combos = []
    n = len(nums)

    def add_permutations(nums, combo=[]):
        # when the combos hit the target length, it's complete
        if len(combo) == n:
            combos.append(combo)
        # otherwise, you just keep adding to the combo with the remaining nums
        for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
            # add to combo and get remaining nums
            combo.append(num)
            remaining_nums = nums[:idx] + nums[idx + 1:]
            # call again at new call depth
            add_permutations(remaining_nums, combo)
            # remove last addition so base combo remains same for all calls at this level
            combo.pop()

    add_permutations(nums)
    return combos

nums = [1,2,3]
print(get_permutations(nums))
```

```
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Why?

```py
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_list == my_list[:]
```

returns `True`, so shouldn't these be the same object? Why does it yield different outputs?

Comment: See also: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1258041)

Comment: See common gotcha #1 [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `my_list[:]`, you are doing a one-level copy; that is, there's a new list with the same contents. Because integers are immutable, this is esentially a new list. You can see this with the `is` operator:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(my_list is my_list) # True
print(my_list is my_list[:]) # False
```

Thus, when you do `combo[:]`, you're creating a new list. When you don't do that, and then you change the new list, you change the `combo` already added to `combos`. Thus, when you `pop()`, you pop from all the lists. Because of this, it's considered a bad practice to pass mutable objects as default arguments. (That's not what's causing the problem in this case, but that doesn't mean it's good.)